# How to tell if a variable is a string or a list, or etc in SIkuli?

Tags: python, variables, sikuli

I would like to check if variable is a string or a list, or etc in Sikuli?
I mean variables that are currently been used in the IDLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in Python, you can use `type(varName)` to determine the variable type. Sikuli however, is using `type()` for a different purpose and hence another method should be used. There are few options.

1. `isinstance()`.
2. `matches.__class__`
3. Just by printing the value. In many cases it is easy enough to see what type the variable is just by printing it. For example, if the variable is printed with `[]` - that's a list, `{}` - dictionary, etc...

Example:

```
>>> lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> isinstance(lst1, list)
True
>>> lst1.__class__
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene could you please give me an example of how... instanste() is used???? and how... matches.__class__ is used???? Thanks Advanced.